# Creating memory game, how to handle large number of images in Android?

Tags: android, image, memory

I am creating an Android memory game. The memory game will consist of images and then the user will match the image to another similar image. I have a prototype ready that works with simple stings, but how should I insert the few hundreds of images I have into the application and what is the best way to keep track of the matches, to see if the user has selected a matching pair? Should I come up with a simple naming convention and figure out the matches from there? Or how should I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You only need to show 2 images (faces) and another one for the card deck. Then remove the paired cards and leave an emoty space in their place. This will prevent OutOfMemory Exceptions

Comment: Yes I know, but how should I know if they are paired? And where should I put all the images, in which Android folder, where should I store them?

Comment: `how should I know if they are paired?` You know the logic of your game... `where should I put all the images` - In the drawable folder, as all the graphics resources. You should already know that.

Comment: My question is, what is the best way to know if they are paired or not? Should I for example name one image 'abc' and then the pair 'abc_pair' or how sould I keep track of them? Yes I know that I can put them there, but is that the most convenient place?

Comment: My friend... you have to study an algorhitm. If it doesn't work for any reason out of your knowledge, we can help you fix it. But you have to show some effort.

Comment: abc and abc_pair should be identical? Correct? If so, then don't confuse your view with your controller. Both views of identical cards should have the exact same name. And yes, use the drawables resource folder for that purpose, that's the most convenient.

Comment: They are representing the same thing, but are different images.

Comment: Are they identical? Please be more specific. What do you mean they're different? I've never seen such a Memory game where the matching cards are different.

Comment: Its a twist. Works like a memory game where images have to be paired, but a pair consist of two different images representing the same thing.

Comment: In any case, it doesn't really matter. If you were playing Memory with a deck of Poker cards, you'd have to use different names like 1h and 1d (for ace of heart and ace of diamond), or your own custom name scheme. That would impact your logic a little bit, but not by very much.